# Is there a problem with IO.Compression?

Tags: .net, vb.net, compression, gzip, gzipstream

I've just started compressing file in VB.Net, using the following code. Since I'm targeting Fx 2.0, I can't use the `Stream.CopyTo` method.

My code, however, gives extremely poor results compared to the gzip `Normal` compression profile in 7-zip. For example, my code compressed a 630MB outlook archive to 740MB, and 7-zip makes it 490MB.

Here is the code. Is there a blatant mistake (or many?)

```
Using Input As New IO.FileStream(SourceFile, IO.FileMode.Open, IO.FileAccess.Read, IO.FileShare.Read)
    Using outFile As IO.FileStream = IO.File.Create(DestFile)
        Using Compress As IO.Compression.GZipStream = New IO.Compression.GZipStream(outFile, IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Compress)
            'TODO: Figure out the right buffer size.'
            Dim Buffer(524228) As Byte
            Dim ReadBytes As Integer = 0

            While True
                ReadBytes = Input.Read(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length)
                If ReadBytes <= 0 Then Exit While
                Compress.Write(Buffer, 0, ReadBytes)
            End While
        End Using
    End Using
End Using
```

I've tried with multiple buffer sizes, but I get similar compression times, and exactly the same compression ratio.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT, or actually rewrite:** It looks like the BCL coders decided to [phone it in](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=phone%20it%20in).

The implementation in `System.dll` version 2.0 uses [statically defined, hardcoded Huffman trees](http://www.virtualdub.org/blog/pivot/entry.php?id=134) optimized for plain ASCII text, rather than adaptively generating the Huffman trees as other implementations do.  It also doesn't support stored-block optimization (which is how standard GZip/Deflate avoid runaway expansion).  As a result, running any sort of file through their implementation other than plain text will result in a much larger file than the input, and Microsoft [claims this is by design!](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/93636/gzipstream-deflatestream-increase-file-size-on-compression)

Save yourself some pain, grab a [third party implementation](http://www.sharpdevelop.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/).

Comment: I'm not using the 7-zip algorithm; I'm using the program called 7-zip (https://sourceforge.net/projects/sevenzip/) to compress to gzip.

Comment: @CFP Ah, good point.  The BCL may just have a crappy implementation of GZip, then -- they certainly don't seem to give you any control over the compression parameters, and if it expands input that much it probably doesn't support the stored-block feature of deflate.  Personally, I use ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib instead; it's pure verifiable managed code to boot.

Comment: I've reopened a bug report, at https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/643239/the-gzip-deflate-implementation-is-broken .

Answer (score 1):

IO.Compression wasn't really made for us. It was created the support the XPS or XML Paper Specificatin. Currently you have to use a third party library if you want decent file compression.

Comment: How come then that the doc reads "This class represents the gzip data format, which uses an industry standard algorithm for lossless file compression and decompression."?

Comment: The documentation isn't wrong, it just doesn't tell the whole story. I too made the mistake of trying to use it before I learned the backstory.

Answer (score 0):

Some additional information that may be useful.
I was compressing some static files (binary) to include in a project release and had the same issue where the file size increased with IO.Compression.GZipStream.

I decided to use Ionic.Zip instead where the best compression could be used.

One thing I noticed immediately is that even though Ionic.Zip reduced my files to 25% of there original size the Compressing Action was about 3-4 times slower (totally expected) but the unzip process was also 3 times slower which made the decompress take 1.6 seconds compared to 0.5 seconds.

Since the GZipStream is a standard, even though the built in IO.Compression.GZipStream in .NET was far less space efficient compressing, it was far faster decompressing.

So I use **both** Ionic.Zip Librarys "**ZLib.GZipStream**" to **Compress** the files and "**IO.Compression.GZipStream**" to **Decompress** the files much faster in production.