# VB.NET Decompress String using GZipStream

Tags: vb.net, compression, gzipstream

I'm trying to compress a string, store it in a variable, and then decompress it (using `GZipStream`), but nothing I try seems to work and everything I'm browsing doesn't help. The string is compressed properly, but then I just can't decompress it back. In this example, the variable `DecompressedString` should be "Hello world!" but it's just empty.

To be clear, the function that compress the string "Hello world!" works fine, and the end result is "H4sIAAAAAAAEAA==". My problem is that i need to store the compressed string in a string variable, and eventually decompress it back. I'm trying to decompress the string "H4sIAAAAAAAEAA==" back into "Hello world!", but the end result of the decompression is an empty string.

```vb
Dim InputString As String = "Hello world!"
Dim CompressedString As String = ""
Dim DecompressedString As String = ""

Dim inputBytes() As Byte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(InputString)

Using outputStream As New MemoryStream
    Using gZipStream As New GZipStream(outputStream, CompressionMode.Compress)
        gZipStream.Write(inputBytes, 0, inputBytes.Length)

        Dim outputBytes = outputStream.ToArray()

        CompressedString = Convert.ToBase64String(outputBytes)
        MsgBox(CompressedString) 'At this point, CompressedString="H4sIAAAAAAAEAA=="
    End Using
End Using

inputBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(CompressedString)

Using inputStream As New MemoryStream(inputBytes)
    Using gZipStream As New GZipStream(inputStream, CompressionMode.Decompress)
        Using streamReader As New StreamReader(gZipStream)
            DecompressedString = streamReader.ReadToEnd()
            MsgBox(DecompressedString)
        End Using
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.NET GZipStream decompress producing empty stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11915612/net-gzipstream-decompress-producing-empty-stream)

Comment: Have you checked what `outputBytes` actually contains, at that point? Just add `gZipStream.Flush()` before `Dim outputBytes = outputStream.ToArray()` -- Your decompressed string is empty because the compressed string is really empty (or, it doesn't contain your source text).

Comment: @Jimi outputBytes.length=10. Everything is OK up to MsgBox(CompressedString), at the string stored="H4sIAAAAAAAEAA==" My problem is to decompress the string "H4sIAAAAAAAEAA==" to "Hello world!".

Comment: All you have there is a gzip header. So it is _not_ ok up to there.