# GZIP outputs and sizes between C#/dot Net and Java

Tags: java, .net, gzip

I am testing the feasibility of compressing some messaging between Java and C#.
The messaging used ranges from small strings (40bytes) to larger strings (4K).

I have found differences in the output of Java GZIP implementation to the dot Net GZIP implementation.

I'm guessing that dot Net has a larger header that is causing the large overhead.
I prefer the Java implementation as it works better on small strings, and would like the dot Net to achieve similar results.

Output, Java version 1.6.0_10

```
Text:EncodeDecode
Bytes:(12 bytes)RW5jb2RlRGVjb2Rl  <- Base64
Compressed:(29)H4sIAAAAAAAAAHPNS85PSXVJBZEAd9jYdgwAAAA=
Decompressed:(12)RW5jb2RlRGVjb2Rl
Converted:EncodeDecode

Text:EncodeDecodeEncodeDecodeEncodeDecodeEncodeDecodeEncodeDecodeEncodeDecodeEncodeDecodeEncodeDecodeEncodeDecodeEncodeDecode
Bytes:(120)RW5jb2RlRGVjb2RlRW5jb2RlRGVjb2RlRW5jb2RlRGVjb2RlRW5jb2RlRGVjb2RlRW5jb2RlRGVjb2RlRW5jb2RlRGVjb2RlRW5jb2RlRGVjb2RlRW5jb2RlRGVjb2RlRW5jb2RlRGVjb2RlRW5jb2RlRGVjb2Rl
Compressed:(33)H4sIAAAAAAAAAHPNS85PSXVJBZGudGQDAOcKnrd4AAAA
Decompressed:(120)RW5jb2RlRGVjb2RlRW5jb2RlRGVjb2RlRW5jb2RlRGVjb2RlRW5jb2RlRGVjb2RlRW5jb2RlRGVjb2RlRW5jb2RlRGVjb2RlRW5jb2RlRGVjb2RlRW5jb2RlRGVjb2RlRW5jb2RlRGVjb2RlRW5jb2RlRGVjb2Rl
Converted:EncodeDecodeEncodeDecodeEncodeDecodeEncodeDecodeEncodeDecodeEncodeDecodeEncodeDecodeEncodeDecodeEncodeDecodeEncodeDecode
```

Output, dot Net 2.0.50727

```
Text:EncodeDecode
Bytes:(12)RW5jb2RlRGVjb2Rl
Compressed:(128)H4sIAAAAAAAEAO29B2AcSZYlJi9tynt/SvVK1+B0oQiAYBMk2JBAEOzBiM3mkuwdaUcjKasqgcplVmVdZhZAzO2dvPfee++999577733ujudTif33/8/XGZkAWz2zkrayZ4hgKrIHz9+fB8/Ik6X02qWP83x7/8Dd9jYdgwAAAA=
Decompressed:(12)RW5jb2RlRGVjb2Rl
Text:EncodeDecode

Text:EncodeDecodeEncodeDecodeEncodeDecodeEncodeDecodeEncodeDecodeEncodeDecodeEncodeDecodeEncodeDecodeEncodeDecodeEncodeDecode
Bytes:(120)RW5jb2RlRGVjb2RlRW5jb2RlRGVjb2RlRW5jb2RlRGVjb2RlRW5jb2RlRGVjb2RlRW5jb2RlRGVjb2RlRW5jb2RlRGVjb2RlRW5jb2RlRGVjb2RlRW5jb2RlRGVjb2RlRW5jb2RlRGVjb2RlRW5jb2RlRGVjb2Rl
Compressed:(131)H4sIAAAAAAAEAO29B2AcSZYlJi9tynt/SvVK1+B0oQiAYBMk2JBAEOzBiM3mkuwdaUcjKasqgcplVmVdZhZAzO2dvPfee++999577733ujudTif33/8/XGZkAWz2zkrayZ4hgKrIHz9+fB8/Ik6X02qWP83x7w/z9/8H5wqet3gAAAA=
Decompressed:(120)RW5jb2RlRGVjb2RlRW5jb2RlRGVjb2RlRW5jb2RlRGVjb2RlRW5jb2RlRGVjb2RlRW5jb2RlRGVjb2RlRW5jb2RlRGVjb2RlRW5jb2RlRGVjb2RlRW5jb2RlRGVjb2RlRW5jb2RlRGVjb2RlRW5jb2RlRGVjb2Rl
Text:EncodeDecodeEncodeDecodeEncodeDecodeEncodeDecodeEncodeDecodeEncodeDecodeEncodeDecodeEncodeDecodeEncodeDecodeEncodeDecode
```

How can I achieve the smaller sized encoding on the dot Net side?

Note, 
Java implementation can decode dot Net implementation and 
dot Net implementation can decode Java implementation.

Java Code

```
@Test
public void testEncodeDecode()
{
    final String strTitle = "EncodeDecode";
    try
    {
        debug( "Text:" + strTitle );

        byte[] ba = strTitle.getBytes( "UTF-8" );
        debug( "Bytes:" + toString( ba ) );

        byte[] eba = encode_GZIP( ba );
        debug( "Encoded:" + toString( eba ) );

        byte[] ba2 = decode_GZIP( eba );
        debug( "Decoded:" + toString( ba2 ) );

        debug( "Converted:" + new String( ba2, "UTF-8" ) );
    }
    catch( Exception ex ) { fail( ex ); }
}
@Test
public void testEncodeDecode2()
{
    final String strTitle = "EncodeDecode";
    try
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for( int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++ ) sb.append( strTitle );

        debug( "Text:" + sb.toString() );

        byte[] ba = sb.toString().getBytes( ENCODING );
        debug( "Bytes:" + toString( ba ) );

        byte[] eba = encode_GZIP( ba );
        debug( "Encoded:" + toString( eba ) );

        byte[] ba2 = decode_GZIP( eba );
        debug( "Decoded:" + toString( ba2 ) );

        debug( "Converted:" + new String( ba2, ENCODING ) );
    }
    catch( Exception ex ) { fail( ex ); }
}
private String toString( byte[] ba )
{
    return "("+ba.length+")"+Base64.byteArrayToBase64( ba );
}
protected static byte[] encode_GZIP( byte[] baData ) throws IOException
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream( baData );
    GZIPOutputStream zos = new GZIPOutputStream( baos );

    byte[] baBuf = new byte[ 1024 ];
    int nSize;
    while( -1 != ( nSize = bais.read( baBuf ) ) )
    {
        zos.write( baBuf, 0, nSize );
        zos.flush();
    }
    Utilities.closeQuietly( zos );
    Utilities.closeQuietly( bais );
    return baos.toByteArray();
}
protected static byte[] decode_GZIP( byte[] baData ) throws IOException
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream( baData );
    GZIPInputStream zis = new GZIPInputStream( bais );

    byte[] baBuf = new byte[ 1024 ];
    int nSize;
    while( -1 != ( nSize = zis.read( baBuf ) ) )
    {
        baos.write( baBuf, 0, nSize );
        baos.flush();
    }
    Utilities.closeQuietly( zis );
    Utilities.closeQuietly( bais );

    return baos.toByteArray();
}


private void debug( Object o ) { System.out.println( o ); }
private void fail( Exception ex )
{
    ex.printStackTrace();
    Assert.fail( ex.getMessage() );
}
```

dot Net Code

```
    [Test]
    public void TestJava6()
    {
        string strData = "EncodeDecode";
        Console.WriteLine("Text:" + strData);

        byte[] baData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strData);
        Console.WriteLine("Bytes:" + toString(baData));

        byte[] ebaData2 = encode_GZIP(baData);
        Console.WriteLine("Encoded:" + toString(ebaData2));

        byte[] baData2 = decode_GZIP(ebaData2);
        Console.WriteLine("Decoded:" + toString(baData2));

        Console.WriteLine("Text:" + Encoding.UTF8.GetString(baData2));
    }
    [Test]
    public void TestJava7()
    {
        string strData = "EncodeDecode";

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) sb.Append(strData);

        Console.WriteLine("Text:" + sb.ToString());

        byte[] baData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Bytes:" + toString(baData));

        byte[] ebaData2 = encode_GZIP(baData);
        Console.WriteLine("Encoded:" + toString(ebaData2));

        byte[] baData2 = decode_GZIP(ebaData2);
        Console.WriteLine("Decoded:" + toString(baData2));

        Console.WriteLine("Text:" + Encoding.UTF8.GetString(baData2));
    }
    public string toString(byte[] ba)
    {
        return "(" + ba.Length + ")" + Convert.ToBase64String(ba);
    }
    protected static byte[] decode_GZIP(byte[] ba)
    {
        MemoryStream writer = new MemoryStream();
        using (GZipStream zis = new GZipStream(new MemoryStream(ba), CompressionMode.Decompress))
        {
            Utilities.CopyStream(zis, writer);
        }
        return writer.ToArray();
    }
    protected static byte[] encode_GZIP(byte[] ba)
    {
        using (MemoryStream reader = new MemoryStream(ba))
        {
            MemoryStream writer = new MemoryStream();
            using (GZipStream zos = new GZipStream(writer, CompressionMode.Compress))
            {
                Utilities.CopyStream(reader, zos);
            }
            return writer.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you working on Strings or bytes? Show us the code!

Comment: Code added, thanks for taking the time to look.

Comment: Hm... At first I thought the Strings might be encoded differently on both platforms (ie. not both UTF-8). But this doesn't seem to be the case. Have you tried the alternative constructor `GZipStream(Stream, CompressionLevel, Boolean)` with different compression levels yet? Perhaps the Java implementation just defaults to a better compression level. Sorry, I don't have dotnet installed, so I cannot experiment myself.

Comment: I am currently working with dot Net 2.0, compression level is non-configurable. 
I was wondering if updating to a later dot Net would provide help my cause, however I am not set up to try the later frameworks.

Comment: I noticed you use this loop StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) sb.Append(strData);
and then encode that string. I do not see the same on teh java side. therefore the .net implementation would have a larger string and therefore a larger compressed size

Comment: Apologies, I left out 2 tests to save space. Java testEncodeDecode2 added and dot net TestJava7 added.

Comment: @bandanna2k Ok just wanted to be sure that we are comparing "apples to apples"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of several bugs in the .NET gzip code.  That code should be avoided.  Use [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) instead.  See answer here: [Why does my C# gzip produce a larger file than Fiddler or PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11435200/why-does-my-c-sharp-gzip-produce-a-larger-file-than-fiddler-or-php/11435898#11435898) .

Comment: That is ... astonishing. I knew that the GZip implementation was bad, but I thought it'd been fixed in 4.0. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Why is that astonishing?  It was written by Microsoft.