# GZipStream decompress a compressed file from 4.0 using 4.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, compression

Ok, this is hard to search for and see if there is anyone else that might have run into this problem.

I am using the GZipStream to Compress XML files in my application which was developed using VS 2010 and the .NET 4.0 Framework.  I use this feature to export data from my production databases and then upload them to my clients server, where I then Decompress the file, load the XML and write the data to the database.  This has worked without a problem.

Now, comes the fun part.  I have now upgraded my Development to VS 2012 and .NET 4.5 Framework.  The Compress and Decompress works fine.  So, in my production environment I export work to an XML file, which I then compress.  I take that file and upload to my clients still running .NET 4.0 and it will not Decompress the file.  It doesn't create an error, it just creates a new file with the exact contents of the compressed file.  Of course it isn't XML so it crashes.

Has anyone had this issue?  Any workarounds in .NET 4.5?  Looks like Microsoft changed the way it compresses using that same code in 4.5?  Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: can you post the code that decompresses the file in .NET 4.5?

Comment: How do you upload it?  Are you certain that the file is intact after the transfer?

Answer (score 1):

You should consider something other than .NET's GZipStream.  See [Why does my C# gzip produce a larger file than Fiddler or PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11435200/why-does-my-c-sharp-gzip-produce-a-larger-file-than-fiddler-or-php/11435898#11435898) and other links from there.

You may have found yet another bug in the pre-4.5 version of GZipStream.  Can you provide the first 20 or so bytes of the stream from the client end (after uploading it)?