# Prevent GZipStream/DeflateStream from trying to consume more than the compressed data

Tags: .net, stream, compression, gzipstream, deflatestream

I have a file that could have been created something like this:

```
stream.Write(headerBytes, 0, headerBytes.Count);

using (var gz = new GZipStream(stream, Compress, leaveOpen: true);
{
    gz.Write(otherBytes, 0, otherBytes.Count);
}

stream.Write(moreBytes, 0, moreBytes.Count);
```

Now when reading the file like

```
stream.Read(headerBytes, 0, headerBytes.Count);
// in reality I make sure that indeed headerBytes.Count get read,
// something the above line omits

using (var gz = new GZipStream(stream, Decompress, leaveOpen: true)
{
  do { /* use buffer... */}
  while ((bytesRead = gz.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0);
}

while ((bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
  // use buffer...
```

It turns out that the `GZipStream` (same is true for `DeflateStream`) reads in 16384 bytes from `stream`, instead of the actual 13293 compressed bytes in the case I checked.

Assuming I neither know the size of the compressed part of the file beforehand, nor the number of bytes following the compressed data, is there a way to use GzipStream/DeflateStream

1. so it only reads the compressed data from `stream`
2. or at least figure out what the size of the compressed data part was, so I can `stream.Position -= actuallyRead - compressedSize` manually?

Answer (score 1):

That interface does not appear to provide a means to do what you want, which is [one of many reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11435898/1180620) to not use .NET's GZipStream or DeflateStream.

You should use [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

This answer amounts to an **ugly workaround**. I don't particularly like it, but it does work (except when it doesn't) even if only for `GZipStream`.

> 2. or at least figure out what the size of the compressed data part was, so I can `stream.Position -= actuallyRead - compressedSize`
>    manually?

As every gzip file (and in fact every *gzip member*) [ends with](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1952#page-5)

```
     +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
     |     CRC32     |     ISIZE     |
     +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+

     CRC32
        This contains a Cyclic Redundancy Check value of the
        uncompressed data

     ISIZE
        This contains the size of the original (uncompressed) input
        data modulo 2^32.
```

I could just use the uncompressed size (module 2^32), which I know after closing the `GzipStream`, and seek backwards in the stream until I find those 4 bytes matching it.

To make it more robust, I should also calculate the CRC32 while uncompressing, and seek backwards in the stream to right after the 8 bytes forming the correct CRC32 and ISIZE.

Ugly, but I did warn you.

<sarcasm>How I love *encapsulation*. Encapsulating all the useful stuff away, leaving us with a decompressing Stream that works in exactly the one use case the all-knowing API designer foresaw.</sarcasm>

Here's a quick `SeekBack` implementation that works so far:

```
/// <returns>the number of bytes sought back (including bytes.Length)
///          or 0 in case of failure</returns>
static int SeekBack(Stream s, byte[] bytes, int maxSeekBack)
{
    if (maxSeekBack != -1 && maxSeekBack < bytes.Length)
        throw new ArgumentException("maxSeekBack must be >= bytes.Length");

    int soughtBack = 0;
    for (int i = bytes.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        while ((maxSeekBack == -1 || soughtBack < maxSeekBack)
               && s.Position > i)
        {
            s.Position -= 1;
            // as we are seeking back, the following will never become
            // -1 (EOS), so coercing to byte is OK
            byte b = (byte)s.ReadByte();
            s.Position -= 1;
            soughtBack++;
            if (b == bytes[i])
            {
                if (i == 0)
                    return soughtBack;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                var bytesIn = (bytes.Length - 1) - i;
                if (bytesIn > 0) // back to square one
                {
                    soughtBack -= bytesIn;
                    s.Position += bytesIn;
                    i = bytes.Length - 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // no luck? return to original position
    s.Position += soughtBack;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following Mark Adler's suggestion, I tried [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/), and lo and behold, its `GZipStream.Position` property does not only not throw, it even returns the number of actual gzip bytes read in (plus 8, for some reason that I still have to figure out).

So it does read more than strictly necessary, but it lets me calculate how much to backtrack.

The following works for me:

```
var posBefore = fileStream.Position;
long compressedBytesRead;
using (var gz = new GZipStream(fileStream, CompressionMode.Decompress, true))
{
    while (gz.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length) != 0)
        ; // use it!
    compressedBytesRead = gz.Position;
}
var gzipStreamAdvance = fileStream.Position - posBefore;
var seekBack = gzipStreamAdvance - compressedBytesRead - 8; // but why "- 8"?
fileStream.Position -= seekBack;
```