# How to enable compression on IIS 10 on Windows 10?

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-mvc-5, windows-10, iis-10

So I've read a lot of answers and questions and still cannot make this work.
I have enabled the compression (both static and dynamic) in IIS.
I have added the lines in the web config of the ASP.NET MVC 5 app (even though I am not sure they are necessary).
My headers are accepting Gzip Encoding.
I even turned off the windows defender (some guy posted that his problem was with the antivirus software).

And still - IIS does not want to send me Content Encoding - Gzip.

I am running out of ideas and answers - so if anyone knows the holy grail.. please, do share!

Comment: Failed request tracing can be used to look deeper, https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/friis/2017/09/05/iis-dynamic-compression-and-new-dynamic-compression-features-in-iis-10/

Comment: try to check the C:\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files\application pool name folder is there any folder available there is or not. also check the folder permission try to give iis_iusrs and iusr permission. did you enable compression at the site level or server level? refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31529076/gzip-compression-not-working-asp-net-mvc5) and [link1](https://forums.asp.net/t/2157968.aspx?Compression+GZIP+doesn+t+work+in+MVC) for more detail.

Comment: @JalpaPanchal Tried them, doesn't work

Comment: @LexLi that link actually helped me, I finally managed to get response with compression but it is BR - Brotli - do you know how can I override it with Gzip? I think chrome has something to do with it..?

Comment: could you share the web.config file?

Comment: @JalpaPanchal it is a project for work so unfortunately I cannot share it, but I solved the problem with the link from Lex . It turned out that I haven't configured which dynamic/static types need to be returned with compression (the collections). Strange because I remember that I did it.., but now it is OK I think.

Comment: you can post the solution as an answer and mark it. it will help other people who face a similar issue. thank you for understanding.