# Unzip Byte Array in C#

Tags: c#, gzip, unzip

I'm working on EBICS protocol and i want to read a data in an XML File to compare with another file.

I have successfull decode data from base64 using 
`Convert.FromBase64String(OrderData);` but now i have a byte array.

To read the content i have to unzip it. I tried to unzip it using Gzip like this example :

```
static byte[] Decompress(byte[] data)
{
    using (var compressedStream = new MemoryStream(data))
    using (var zipStream = new GZipStream(compressedStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
    using (var resultStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        zipStream.CopyTo(resultStream);
        return resultStream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

But it does not work i have an error message :

> the magic number in gzip header is not correct. make sure you are passing in a gzip stream

Now i have no idea how i can unzip it, please help me !

Thanks !

Comment: Can you show how you are compressing the data?

Comment: I haven't compress data, i want to read the data compressed

Comment: Are you sure your `OrderData` has been compressed with `GZipStream` before being encoded to base64 and written to XML file?

Comment: It's not encoded with GzipStream but there is the only one is available in my .NET Framework

Comment: Then how it has been encoded?

Comment: The data are first zipped and base64 encoded

Comment: Save the `byte[] data` to a temp file. Then try to open it from Windows Explorer. Could you? With which program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first four bytes provided by the OP in a comment to another answer: `0x78 0xda 0xe5 0x98` is the start of a zlib stream.  It is neither gzip, nor zip, but zlib.  You need a `ZlibStream`, which for some reason Microsoft does not provide.  That's fine though, since [what Microsoft does provide is buggy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11435898/1180620).

You should use [DotNetZip](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DotNetZip/), which provides `ZlibStream`, and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [SharpZipLib](https://icsharpcode.github.io/SharpZipLib/). It copes with various compression formats and is free under the GPL license.

As others have pointed out, I suspect you have a zip stream and not gzip. If you check the first 4 bytes in a hex view, ZIP files always start with 0x04034b50 [ZIP File Format Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)#File_headers) whereas GZIP files start with 0x8b1f [GZIP File Format Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip#File_format)

Comment: It's not a File juste byte array

Comment: list the first 4 bytes please.

Comment: converting your first number 120218229152217 to hex gives 0x72A6275 which I am not familiar with. Your edit is also an unfamiliar sequence.

Answer (score 0):

I think I finally got it - as usual the problem is not what is in the title. Luckily I've noticed the word EBICS in your post.  So, according to EBICS spec the data is first compressed, then **encrypted** and finally base64 encoded. As you see, after decoding base64 you need first to **decrypt** the data and then try to unzip it.

**UPDATE:** If that's not the case, it turns out from the EBICS spec *Chapter 16 Appendix: Standards and references* that ZIP refers to zlib/deflate format, so all you need to do is to replace `GZipStream` with the [DeflateStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.deflatestream(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: In HIA request, orders in EBICS message are not encrypted